# Monitoring Linux writes to Compact Flash

Tags: linux, flash, logging

I am working on a project that uses a SanDisk compact flash to host a linux operating system (ext2 file system and no swap). The system uses a separate IDE for logging and other file i/o functions. Looking around online it seems standard that compact flash cards are capable of 100,000 or so write cycles (taking into account the load balancing). There are plenty of good questions on SuperUser about how to reduce the number of writes but I would like to know if there **is there any way to monitor/log the number of writes to the compact flash**. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I kept digging deeper and found a few options:

> smartcrl

This command found in the smartmontools package will list the number of write commands (including logical sectors written) and some other neat stats. https://linuxconfig.org/retrieve-hard-drive-s-age-and-general-health-information-using-linux. But my compact flash lacks SMART capability so that won't work.

> /sys/block/dev/stat

This file provides several statistics about the state of block device "dev" including what I am looking for - number of write I/Os processed. https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/block/stat.txt

> vmstat -d

This command also shows different i/o statistics. Basically the same info as /sys/block/dev/stat but for all disk statistics. Would have to grep a bit to get the sda device that I am interested in.

There were a couple other things that I looked at such as diskstat and some commands listed at tecmint.com concerning linux-performance-monitoring-with-vmstat-and-iostat-commands (I needed at least 10 rep points to post more than 2 links).

I think the /sys/block/dev/stat approach will best fit my needs.